# How to connect datalab with Google Cloud SQL?

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-datalab

Trying to connect from a datalab notebook with PostgreSQL database hosted on Google Cloud SQL. Try both direct IP and instance connection ways but both give us an exception.

direct connection URI:

```
"{engine}://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}"
```

using gcloud sql connect

```
"{engine}://{user}:{password}@/{database}?host=/cloudsql/{instance_connection_name}"
```

both give us this exception:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to 
server: Connection timed out
  Is the server running on host "***.***.***.***" and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port ****?
```

Any idea if it need a cloud sql proxy as in [Collab proxy connection](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SQCvWqCUAkqVHjfaEuLTBMBzxVdl7Q9h)? And if it is needed how to do it with datalab libraries?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it.

Assuming that datalab VM is already authenticated on Gcloud i try to use  cloud_sql_proxy to connect without auth python commands that appear on [Collab proxy connection](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1SQCvWqCUAkqVHjfaEuLTBMBzxVdl7Q9h) and fix the error that still appears by crating missing directory. Si i got this:

```
!wget https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.amd64 -O cloud_sql_proxy
!mkdir -p /cloudsql
!chmod +x cloud_sql_proxy
```

.

```
!./cloud_sql_proxy --instances=project-id:europe-west1:posty --dir /cloudsql
```

as with Collab solution we need to let the notebook running in alternate window to keep proxy. With other notebooks on the same machine we finally obtain access to the database.

**Note**: Probably a better solution could be to edit the docker image of datalab machines to include this behaviour as noted [here](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/wiki/Getting-Started).

Answer (score 0):

IT may be that your VM machine ip isn't whitelisted on the database.

You can access the list and add new ips on the google cloud console SQL > yor_database > authorization.

Check this link for details https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app?hl=en_US&_ga=2.178999533.-851571953.1521816449#appaccessIP

Comment: It works but it is only temporary. The external IP assigned for datalab instance is 'ephimeral' and changes every time the machine is launched. 

However i tested to see if it works, result was positive. While i keep the instance running i could access the database. But when re-connect to the datalab instance it change IP and stop working as expected.